# jQuery and XPath XML parsing

Tags: jquery, xml, xpath

I want to parse XML using jQuery. Is it possible to parse using XPath? Are there any functions for that in jQuery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not directly, but you can use [jQuery selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) to achieve the same thing.

<sub>Previous versions (1.2) at: http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors</sub>

Comment: Note that XPath selectors were made deprecated in jQuery 1.2 and have been removed altogether in 1.3. But one can still 'translate' your XPath selector to a CSS selector...