# jQuery and xPath solution

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpath, jquery-plugins, firepath

Is there any jQuery plugin or tutorial or some script that works like FirePath in Firefox. What I need is to get Xpath location from code (something like xpather or firepath but written in php, jquery, javascript or some other script). What do you suggest?

Comment: Refer this [Jquery and Xpath XML parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975279/jquery-and-xpath-xml-parsing)

Comment: or any way to integrate firepath in script ???

Comment: Let's say you were writing such a program and ran into some trouble. That's appropriate for SO. Asking the community to write the entire thing for you? Not appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [source code](https://github.com/pierretholence/firepath/tree/master/content) and start a thread on the [FirePath discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/firepath) for help using the API as a standalone library.