# Get specific elements from XML

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an xml document fetched from a server via ajax of the following format.

```
<persons>   
    <person>  
        <first>Jim</first>  
        <last>Smith</last>  
    </person>  
    <person>  
        <first>Jim</first>  
        <last>Smith</last>  
    </person>  
</persons>
```

How can I extract the `first` and `last` values of each `person`?

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
var persons = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('persons');  
           for(var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++ ) {  
               var person = persons[i];  
               var first = person.firstChild.data;  
               console.log(first);  
           }
```

Comment: What does the error console say?

Comment: where have you set the value of xmldoc and where is your AJAX call?

Comment: If I do `console.log(persons)` I see the persons. But nothing is printed in the loop

Comment: try `person.firstChild.nodeValue`

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gt7FT/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstName = person.getElementsByTagName('first');
var lastName = person.getElementsByTagName('last');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var persons = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('person');  

for(var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++ ) {  
    var person = persons[i];  
    var first = person.firstChild.textContent;  
    console.log(first);  
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gt7FT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you parse XML documents and you want to do it *properly*, then you can use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), and load your XML with [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp).

You can also [parse](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) if from a string with jQuery and use [jQuery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975279/jquery-and-xpath-xml-parsing) to select what you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this

first of all add this line in your xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and then try this one using jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery.get("person.xml",{},function(xml) {
    jQuery('person',xml).each(function(i) {
        first = jQuery(this).find("first").text();
        last = jQuery(this).find("last").text();
        alert("First Name-> "+first+"   Last name ->"+last);
    });
});
});
```